# How can we find the volume by integration for $x>0, y>0, z>0$ and $z^2<x+y<2z$?

Tags: integration, 3d

[Intersection of formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7UUs.png)

I am trying to find the volume but I can't use the methods in most videos where I should let every 2 variables be zero and solve for the third since there are no values to start with.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  You can start by just putting `$` signs around math expressions.

Comment: Since $z>0,z^2<2z$ you know that $0<z<2$

Answer (score 0):

All points of this solid $S$ are lying over points  in the first quadrant of the $(x,y)$-plane. For each such point $(x,y)$ we have
$$(x,y,z)\in S\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad {x+y\over2}<z<\sqrt{x+y}\ .$$
It turns out that we need $x+y<2\sqrt{x+y}$, which then implies $x+y<4$. It follows that our domain of integration $S'$ is given by
$$S'=\bigl\{(x,y)\bigm| x>0, \ y>0, \ x+y<4\bigr\}\ ,$$
and we have
$${\rm vol}(S)=\int_{S'}f(x,y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)=\int_0^4\int_0^{4-x}f(x,y)\>dy\>dx\ ,$$
whereby
$$f(x,y):=\sqrt{x+y}-{x+y\over2}\ .$$

Comment: Thank you for your amazing help :D